# Datatables rowReorder jumps back

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to make a dragable datatable, but when I drag the row, the row it jumps back to its original place.

My code looks like this:

**jQuery**

```
var table = $('#'+table_id).DataTable( 
{
    "ordering": false,
    "sScrollY": ($(window).height() - 600),
    "scrollX": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sClass":"table_no_whitespace",

    "columnDefs": [
        { className: 'reorder', targets: 1 },
    ],
    "rowReorder": {
        selector: 'td.reorder'
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="exam_exercises" class="table display table-striped table-bordered mb-none no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; padding: 8px!important">
                <img class="toggle_select_all" which_box="infobox" src="<?= base_url(); ?>img/tickbox/unchecked.png">
            </th>
            <td></td>
            <th>Exercise</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php if (count($exercises) > 0) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($exercises as $exercise) : ?>
                <tr class="itemrow" id="exercise_<?= $exercise['id']; ?>" myid="<?= $exercise['id']; ?>" id="e_<?= $exercise['id']; ?>">
                    <td class="non-selectable tickcell" style="width: 1px; text-align: center">
                        <img class="individual_checkbox" which_box="infobox" id="check_<?= $exercise['id']; ?>" src="<?= base_url(); ?>img/tickbox/unchecked.png">
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" class="reorder"><?= $exercise['sort']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $exercise['exercise_name']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

At the moment my table looks like this:
[image]
I am using the second column as my dragable cell, this column is not used as the default sorting column, because my data is being ordered in the database query.

I believe I might be missing something small, but I have yet to find the solution.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Possibly you need to enable ordering just for your sequence column as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/restrictedOrdering.html), disabling ordering for the whole table probably prevents row reorder plugin from working.

Comment: I managed to get this running after adding an extra hidden column that contains the unique ID for each row. I rewrote the script and reloaded all the correct files, so believe that is what made it work